# index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I was trying to write a programme using python to compute the infinite series of

> 1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 +1/4^2 +.....

my code is as follows:

```
n = 100
x = np.zeros([n])
x[0] = 0
for i in range(n):
   x[i+1] = x[i] + 1/float((i+1)**2)
print x[99]
```

when I tried to execute the code, it returned something as:

> IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

I would like to know what is wrong with the code. Thanks!:)

Comment: Why are you using a numpy array? Being iterated over is not what they are good at; you'd save yourself a headache just by using a python `list` and `.append`.

Comment: @FHTMitchell First of all, thank you for your ans. It helps. I used numpy array because I have been using this all the time. Can you suggest why list and .append would be more convenient? Is it about the computation time?

Comment: No, it would stop you making the mistake you made though. Lists are all about dynamically changing size, whereas with a numpy array you have to predict the size of the array (which causes errors exactly like you had).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Index `i` goes up to `99` so you are trying to get `x[i + 1] == x[100]` at the last iteration, so it can not work because `x` goes up to `x[99]`

In your for loop just do `range(n - 1)`