# IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to loop over pairs of items in tuples, run a Postgres query and then add data to a DataFrame. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Download and import WRDS, using pip if required

try:
   import wrds
except ImportError:
   !pip install wrds
   import wrds

# Connect to wrds
conn = wrds.Connection()

fd_list_most =tuple(["2013-03-01", "2013-03-03", "2013-03-19", "2013-01-29", "2013-03-28", "2013-02-22", "2013-02-27", "2013-03-14", "2013-03-01", "2013-03-18"]);

mcl1=pd.merge(most_cons_list[['gvkey','datadate','bkvlps', 'cik']],mcl,how='left',on=['gvkey'])
print(mcl1);
```

mcl1 output:

```
    gvkey    datadate   bkvlps         cik  permco
0  008007  2013-12-31  29.0228  0000072971   21305
1  028278  2013-12-31  15.1899  0000714395   12139
2  111940  2013-12-31  13.6911  0000765207   16649
3  157955  2013-12-31  28.0769  0001273813   45077
4  180169  2013-12-31  10.4775  0001390312   53031
5  184167  2013-12-31  18.1538  0000860413   53368
```

```
# Loop over each pair of filing date and CIK and retrieve stock price for 7 days either side of filing date

mcl2=pd.DataFrame();


for i in range(len(fd_list_most)):
    stmt3="""
    select permco, ret, retx, date(date) as date
    FROM crsp.dsf
    where permco= {}
    and  date < date '{}' + integer '7'
    and date > date '{}' - integer '7'
    """.format(mcl['permco'].values[i],fd_list_most[i],fd_list_most[i])
    mcl2=mcl2.append(conn.raw_sql(stmt3))

print(mcl2)
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-31f1dfe1daea> in <module>
     11     and  date < date '{}' + integer '7'
     12     and date > date '{}' - integer '7'
---> 13     """.format(mcl['permco'].values[i],fd_list_most[i],fd_list_most[i])
     14     mcl2=mcl2.append(conn.raw_sql(stmt3))
     15 

IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
```

This is sample code from a tutor, which works fine with the data he has entered, but not with mine. 
I can see that there is a problem with the length of my index, but I am not sure how to solve it.
I'd be grateful for any help. I am a beginner, so I do not always understand the more complicated solutions. I have had a look for this question, and had a go at these [IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1/ForwardEuler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059227/indexerror-index-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-1-forwardeuler), [index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820379/index-100-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-100) but they haven't worked for me, possibly because I don't understand how to apply the solutions to my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame looks like it only has 6 entries, whereas you're iterating over a tuple that has more. In your `for` statement, you could just change it to iterate over the rows of `mc12`.

I don't like to recommend using `df.iterrows()`, but in this case it looks like a good fit. Check here: [df.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Also, are you sure this statement is doing what you expect? `mcl2=mcl2.append(conn.raw_sql(stmt3))`
. You didn't post about that one so I won't address it here.

Comment: Thank you, that is the issue. I have requested data which doesn't exist so my DataFrame is smaller than my tuple. Unfortunately the rows of mcl1 do not contain the same data as the tuple. Is there an easy way to solve this where I can use the tuple but have NaN or something similar in place of the data that would be there otherwise?